# Display date/time using external JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I want to put the current date and time in the footer of my XHTML website using an external JavaScript code. I'm aware of the function `document.write`, but how do I make an external script print date/time in different locations within a HTML?

External script:
`function date()`

HTML: The date of today is `date()`

How do I achieve this?

Comment: what do you mean by external script? script downloaded from a different website?

Comment: Tbh, I don't even know what to try. Most of the online examples only show using the document.write function. But I need to be able to call that function externally from anywhere within the HTML.

Comment: No. Just a script located in a different .js file; not inline or embedded.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just include the script in your HTML:

```
<script src="/externalscript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

and then call the function somewhere.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    date();
</script>
```

Now you shouldn't be using `document.write`, instead make an element with an `id` and use JS to modify it.

JS:

```
function date() {
    document.getElementById('mydate').innerHTML = "your date code";
}
```

HTML:

```
<span id="mydate">this will get updated</span>
```

Answer (score 4):

`document.write` is evil, you should learn about [dom](/questions/tagged/dom) manipulation:

```
function date() {
  document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = new Date().toString()
}
```

and somewhere in your HTML:

```
<p>The date of today is <span id="date">?</span></p>
```

However, you need to remember and learn about sooo many things:

- `date()` script needs to be executed after DOM was loaded (or at least after this `<span>` was)
- relying on [raw element IDs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.getElementById) is not advised
- `innerHTML` is kind of low-level
- ...

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I've been only learning JS/CSS/HTML for a month or so. A total newbie :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing that by external script you mean an external .js file you've referenced in your `head` block, e.g. `<script type="text/javascript" src="../randomscript.js"></script>`.

In your HTML you'd need an element with an `id` of `date`.

```
<div id="date">?</date>
```

This is the div that will get updated. In your script you should write

```
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById('date').innerHTML = d;
```

You see, it doesn't really matter where you've referenced the script from, you can still access the DOM using an external script.

Answer (score 0):

I assume an "external script" is a script loaded from an external server, that is, not from the website itself.

The remote script (date.js) simply consists of

```
function showDate(element) {
  element.text = new Date().toString();
}
```

On your website you then call this function

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="http://www.example.org/date.js"></script>
<p>Now is: <span id="date-element" /></p>
<script type="application/javascript">
showDate(document.getElementById('date-element'));
</script>
```

The advantage of passing an element to the function is that the function is generic and does not hard-code identifiers.